# Multiple install paths for qmake INSTALLS

Tags: qt, makefile, qmake

How can I put the compiled binary library file in a several paths using qmake? I have found out that specifying multiple paths in `target.path` leads to overriding targets in a Makefile. Is it possible to make installs into several paths using qmake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have solved with such an addition into .pro file:

```
target1.path=$${PWD}/../relative/install/path/for/depependend/project/1
unix:target1.files=$${DESTDIR}/*.so*
win32:target1.files=$${DESTDIR}/*.dll

target2.path=$${PWD}/../relative/install/path/for/depependend/project/2
unix:target2.files=$${DESTDIR}/*.so*
win32:target2.files=$${DESTDIR}/*.dll

target3.path=$${PWD}/../relative/install/path/for/depependend/project/3
unix:target3.files=$${DESTDIR}/*.so*
win32:target3.files=$${DESTDIR}/*.dll

INSTALLS += target1 target2 target3
```